# Is there a Thrift or Cassandra client for Node.js/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, cassandra, node.js, thrift

I would like to start using Cassandra with a node.js deployment, but I can't find a Thrift or Cassandra client for Node.js and/or JavaScript.

Is there one?

Is there a simple means of generating Thrift connections?

**Update:** The short answer to this question turns out to be no, there is no JS client for Thrift that is compatible with Cassandra.

**Further Update:** The next release of Cassandra (0.8 at time of writing) is going to have support for an [Avro](http://avro.apache.org/) API. There is already node.js module for Avro support.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Someone made one now:
https://github.com/wadey/node-thrift

**Update**:
Rackspace released a node cassandra api:
http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/cassandra-node/

**Update**:
They moved it to github:
https://github.com/racker/node-cassandra-client

**Update**:
There is a CQL driver now too:
https://github.com/simplereach/helenus

**Update**:
There is a CQL driver, that uses the Cassandra native protocol
https://github.com/jorgebay/node-cassandra-cql

**Update**:
DataStax released a CQL driver for Cassandra using the native protocol:
https://github.com/datastax/nodejs-driver

Comment: But how do you use it.
Fails for me.. :(
saying.. "key" has no write method :(

Comment: The docs aren't good, but take a look at the unit test, they helped me.

Answer (score 9):

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-550

edit: take a look at https://github.com/wadey/node-thrift

Comment: which is to say, it's in thrift trunk and will be in the upcoming thrift 0.3 release.

Comment: Cheers. I actually found this one last night and started hacking it to work with node.js

Comment: Will still need to bui8ld a Cassandra lib on top of this, but it's a great start.

Comment: Perhaps you guys could clarify this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955651/thrift-js-compatibility-with-cassandra-json-protocol
:P

Answer (score 1):

Zanson already mentioned that Rackspace released the Cassandra API for Node.js, but it's worth noting that their Google Code page isn't their primary base of operations. The github page is where you can stay the most up to date:

https://github.com/racker/node-cassandra-client

Answer (score 1):

The official Datastax driver is now node-cassandra-cql rebranded to nodejs-driver:

https://github.com/datastax/nodejs-driver

It uses CQL3.