# Thrift JS compatibility with Cassandra (JSON Protocol)

Tags: javascript, cassandra, thrift, thrift-protocol

I have generated a Thrift lib for Cassandra targeting JavaScript from the latest Thrift build in SVN.

However, I noticed in the provided js thrift client library the following statement:

> This client can only speak the JSON
>   Protocol and the only supported
>   transport is AJAX.

Does anyone know if the JSON protocol is compatible with Cassandra?

The transport is not an issue as I am planning on porting this to use a node.js socket, but I need to know if the JSON Protocol is going to allow me to connect with Cassandra.

The Thrift and Cassandra docs are both very light on this front.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CassandraDaemon assumes BinaryProtocol.

Comment: Well, that is quite annoying then. :P

Comment: Part of the reason is, Thrift JSON is broken anyway.  See e.g. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-1049

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra node driver:
http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/cassandra-node/